# Session live timeout when 2 hour

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I'm using PHP Version 5.2.13, session.save_path = no value and wordpress 4.2.2.

I have a problem when i has login with function wp_signon.

```
    $creds                  = array();
    $creds['user_login']    = $_POST['txtLoginID'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['txtLoginPassword'];
    $creds['remember']      = true;
    $user                   = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

But after 2 hour, my account have been logged out.
How to keep login in 2 week. Thank you so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change session expire time in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191359/how-to-change-session-expire-time-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the `lifetime` parameter of the [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) function. It will allow you to set it to 2 weeks.