# Call 'wp_logout' when cookie expires (php or javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cookies, session-cookies

I am looking for a way to call `wp_logout` (server side) if my `wordpress_logged_in_HASH` cookie expires. Unfortunalty I can't find any solution so far. Did a lot of research on stackoverflow and google, but still not done.
Does anyone have some advices or ideas how to do it?

Server side I can check if the cookie exits with `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`. The variable exits on my shared server and this works. But how to run `wp_logout` automaticly when cookie expires? Maybe by some javascript?

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'], 'wordpress_logged_in') == true){
    echo "Login cookie exists!<br>";
    var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    //echo($startTime = microtime(true));
} else{
    echo "Login cookie not exists!";
    var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    }
```

Comment: `$_COOKIE['wordpress_logged_in']` would probably be somewhat more secure. Neither are that secure though. Should check server side for session, not a cookie

Comment: `$_COOKIE['wordpress_logged_in']` is not available. Actually `$_COOKIE` is always empty. Do you know, why it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change session expire time, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21356746/8740349), by adding in your theme's `functions.php` something like:

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_expiration_filter', 99, 3);
function my_expiration_filter($seconds, $user_id, $remember){

    //if "remember me" is checked;
    if ( $remember ) {
        //WP defaults to 2 weeks;
        $expiration = 14*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
    } else {
        //WP defaults to 48 hrs/2 days;
        $expiration = 2*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
    }

    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem
    if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
        //Fix to a little bit earlier!
        $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
    }

    return $expiration;
}
```

---

Surprisingly enough, `WordPress` does not use `PHP` sessions at all. It uses only cookies. And it uses a number of them with hashed names.

So don't mess with them directly, and do it the WordPress way with filters like above.

Or by calling `WordPress` APIs. E.g. if you want to log out the current user, you can call `wp_clear_auth_cookie`:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_auth_cookie

Comment: Thanks, but the user should get logged out automaticly without page reload. And your code about doesn't match this requirement. Any further ideas?

Comment: @cr4nk This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/477156); WordPress will logout users once time is expired, with or without page reload; Seems you do not care that WordPress will logout automatically, and you just want to somehow ensure `wp_logout` is called (probably you have some logout-action which you need triggered).